# HERE Autocomplete API: Horribly Inaccurate Results, Ignores House Numbers

Tags: autocomplete, here-api

Getting really inaccurate results w/ HERE Autocomplete API.

Example:
Searching for "2215 E 2" in US with proximity lat/lon set just blocks away from location:

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=2215+e+2&maxresults=50&country=USA&language=en&prox=40.593791,-73.961245&resultType=houseNumber
```

Returns results that don't even have '2215' as house number or not even at least a partial string match of "2215 E 2" - here are some examples of incorrectly returned results:

```
"United States, NY, Brooklyn, 2002 E 2nd St"
"United States, NY, Brooklyn, 2003 E 21st St"
"United States, NY, Brooklyn, 2001 E 22nd St"
"United States, NY, Brooklyn, 2001 E 13th St"
"United States, NY, Brooklyn, 2002 E 8th St"
"United States, NY, Brooklyn, 2001 E 19th St"
```

Looks like HERE API completely ignores house number in many cases. But for some reason when searching for the same using the HERE mobile app, I get correct results. So there must be something else employed that is not listed in the API docs.

Logically API should first return exact string match, then partial / fuzzy results.

Are there any additional search operators that need to be used in the query string?

How to get exact string match on partial the address like in HERE app?

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete api tries to get matches even for a single letter. Since you have provided prox paramater in your request you are explicitly telling the api that results closer to it are more important to you. That is why the results returned are ordered according to the distance from your prox. You can see the distance displayed in your response. Removing the prox will order the results according to most relevant match.

**prox - A type of Spatial Filter. Sets a focus on a geographic area represented by a single geo-coordinate pair and optionally a radius (in meters) so the results within this area are more important than results outside of this area.**

Update: Try using mapview for your usecase to get the results you need. It is also suggested in developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/using-autocomplete.html.

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=2215+e+2&maxresults=50&country=USA&language=en&mapview=40.593791,-73.961245,;45.2173875,-73.961245,&resultType=houseNumber&beginHighlight=%3Cb%3E&endHighlight=%3C/b%3E
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Removing prox filter gives too many irrelevant results that are in other states / regions and since results are limited to 20, correct result is not present at all. Are there any additional search query operators or is there any way to force it to give more exact match with prox filter? The way it is now it's pretty much USELESS. In the HERE mobile app I see completely different  results from what API gives, they are a lot more accurate and relevant. So there must be some additional techniques used, what are they?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: MapView does not get the job done. None of the 20 results are correct. It matches on single letters like "E" or "ST" and completely ignores the house number. Requesting to escalate this with support. Potentially paying customer here.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. We have raised this with our internal team. We expect this to be fixed asap.